# Did someone manage to monitor windows services with appdynamics?

Tags: monitoring, appdynamics

Normally newer verisons of Appdynamics should display windows services if you add them specificially into the config.xml. I did that, restartet the services and the agent, but nothing happened.
Did anyone manage to display the Services ? If yes, where do they appear?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to completely answer your question and solve the issue with the provided information. However, I hope my questions below help you to get on the right track.

1.) After making the configuration change, did you also restart the AppDynamics.AgentCoordinator_WindowsService? Without restarting it the new configuration will not be applied to the agent itself.

2.) Also important is your windows service hosting any OOTB support entry point like WCF, ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI, web services etc.? If not, you need to setup a custom entry point. If you  check out the AppDynamics documentation and search for'POCO Entry Points' you should get onto the right track

3.) In case No.1 & No.2 did not do the trick, could you please attach the config.xml file for review? Or directly reach out to the AppDynamics customer success team.

Kind regards,
Theo

Disclaimer: I work for AppDynamics as part of the Customer Success team.

Comment: i kept it as simple as that now, without any windows services. but is it still not working :( <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appdynamics-agent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <controller host="MYIP" port="MYPORT" ssl="false">
    <application name="MYAPPNAME" />
  </controller>
  <machine-agent />
  <app-agents>
    <IIS>
      <automatic />
    </IIS>
  </app-agents>
</appdynamics-agent>

Comment: anyway, don't want to know how it's done. there is documentation. I simply want to know IF YOU KNOW SOMEONE WHO MADE THAT. Because appdynamics is not working for us as expected. I even was on a real meeting with appdynamics ace team and, no one could help LOL

Comment: Ray of Command, could you just send an email to help at appdynamics dot com and add to the subject: "windows service setup issue, review by Theo" and I get on a call with you and address the issue. I have worked with many customers you setup windows service instrumentation successfully, so I am sure we can address this issue for you.

Comment: sorry, right now i can't. we have scheduled a call already for 7th.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to you answer and to clarify a little. Until release 3.7.7 the .NET agent from AppDynamics used the web.config (for IIS based application), App.config for standalone and windows services or the global.config plus some environment variables to configure the agent.

With the 3.7.8 or later release we replaced this with a cleaner truly singly configuration file approach. The configuration file is called config.xml and located in the %ProgramData%\AppDynamics... directory. For any version after 3.7.8 all settings have to be in the config.xml.

Comment: Yes I did all that. I put the windows services as discribed in the config , also restartet the AppDynamics.AgentCoordinator_WindowsService and the windows services. Also created custom poco rules to detect any WCF which contains the name "service"  (most of our windows services have service in the name) but still no success. on top of that now appdynamics stops after  1 day of collecting data :( until i rerun the configuration tool. i will work on that today again

Comment: Hi Ray of Command,what version of the agent are you using? And if you say config, which config is this? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: u use the latest agent and the only one config in appdata .netagent config    i guess name i config.xml.  Thank you. Btw i wil have a call with appdynamics guys soon. so please consider this as closed for now. thank

Answer (score 0):

You really should take this up with AppDynamics support by filing a ticket or posting in the support forums... http://www.appdynamics.com/support/#helptab